# NPM audit vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I was installing **npm** package for getting **node module** file but after I run `npm install` it is showing me 184 vulnerabilities(153 low, 1 moderate, 30 high), should i have to run `npm audit fix` in order to fix this, But my concern is that will it make any changes in the already installed dependencies, will it change my `package.json` file and `package-lock.json` file. I have attached the image below.
[image] Please help me out with this Thank you. I just need to know whether will it change all the preinstalled dependencies or is it good to run `npm audit fix` command.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never encountered any problems running npm audit fix on my projects and didn't hear it from anyone else either so I recommend you try it in the worst-case scenario you can just uninstall your packages and install them again using npm install just know that npm audit fix may not fix all of you're vulnerabilities you may need to replace the specific package.
cheers.

Comment: Ok, let me try. Thank you.

Comment: if it worked I'd be thankful if you mark it as answered